# Why does Banshee recognize my Android on Ubuntu, but not on Mythbuntu?

Tags: 11.04, banshee, android, mythbuntu

I have one computer with Ubuntu 11.04, and another computer with Mythbuntu 11.04. Both have Banshee 2.0 installed.

Banshee on the computer running Ubuntu automatically detects my Android device when I plug it in by USB. I can copy files to and from the device within the Banshee interface no problem.

Banshee on the computer running Mythbuntu doesn't detect it. The device does get mounted on the desktop and is accessible via Thunar. It's only Banshee that refuses to see it.

What's the difference that's holding my Mythbuntu machine back?

Comment: On the Mythbuntu computer, try running Banshee from terminal with the command `banshee --debug`.  Then, plug in the phone after Banshee is running and see if any warnings or errors show up in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the list of enabled plugins in both instances (Edit > Preferences > Extensions). In particular, check whether "Mass Storage Media Player Support" is enabled.

[image: Banshee Preferences]

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, I've confirmed that "Mass Storage Media Player Support" is checked on. So is "MTP Media Player Support", "Karma Support", and "Apple Devices Support".